# Who killed Sudama (son of Karna)?

Tags: mahabharata, karna

How many son did Karna have? Is Sudama one of his sons not present in Mahabharat war? Did he die before the war? If so who killed him and why?

Comment: I studied **Mrityunjaya by Shivaji Sawant** in college days..that mention about Karna's son who was killed by Arjuna in Draupadi-Svayamvar..Not sure if that can be considered as a valid source here..

Comment: @YDS You can post here.

Answer (score 2):

In an answer at quora [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Sudama-son-of-Karna-at-age-of-9-years-killed-by-Arjuna-in-Draupadis-Swayamvar) it is said no such character was ever present.

It states

"No such son is either mentioned or
killed at Draupadi’s Swayamvar in
Vyas’ epic. This character was in all
probabilities an invention of Shivaji
Sawant in his legendary
mythological fiction ‘Mrityunjay’."

And the same asserts [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karna)

Karna have other sons [Vrishasena](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrishasena) and Vrishakethu, Sushena and Satyasena.

**UPDATE**

> The two protectors of Karna's
>   car wheels, viz., **his two invincible
>   sons, O sire, that were named
>   Sushena and Satyasena**, began to
>   fight, reckless of their very lives. **The
>   eldest son of Karna, viz., the mighty
>   car-warrior Vrishasena, himself
>   protected his father's rear.**
>
> —[The Mahabharata, Book 8:
>   Karna Parva: Section 48](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08048.htm)

Comment: Don't you think by this way, we ll make Hinduism SE as replica of Quora..

Comment: @YDS i thought that that's why i cited wikipedia too i think you did'nt saw it :)